# heroku - could not find a javascript runtime

Tags: angularjs, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, execjs

I am getting the following error message in the heroku logs when trying to access the application from the browser:

```
 Gem Load Error is: Could not find a
 JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
```

This is being triggered by a couple of gems - `ngannotate-rails` and `coffee-rails`.

This is a `rails 4.2` application with a `angular.js` frontend, being deployed to heroku for the first time.

Heroku stack:

```
$ heroku stack
=== my_app Available Stacks
  heroku-16
* cedar-14
```

Buildpacks:

```
$ heroku buildpacks
=== my_app Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/prakashmurthy/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
2. heroku/ruby
```

Both the node.js build and ruby build complete successfully.

PATH seems to be set correctly:

```
$ heroku run bash
Running bash on ⬢ my_app... up, run.1502 (Free)
~ $ echo $PATH
/app/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/bin:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Appreciate any help in figuring out this issue.

Comment: You can try adding `therubyracer` to the gemfile, which is an alternative to node.

Comment: Thanks. That did help, and got me to move forward.

Comment: Why the custom buildpack? The default ruby buildpacks already have a JS runtime included with them.

Comment: The custom buildpack is for the angular.js part; to make it look for `package.json` in the `frontend` folder instead of the root. Not sure why the app is not finding the JS runtime included by the ruby buildpack.